# Jflex get input filename

Tags: java, compiler-construction, filenames, jflex

In Jflex, how does one extract the input filename?

DisplayFilename.jflex:

```
%%

%class DisplayFilename

%eof{
    /* code to print the input filename goes here */
%eof}

%%

\n { /* do nothing */ }
. { /* do nothing */ }
```

Commands ran

```
jflex DisplayFilename
javac DisplayFilename.java
java DisplayFilename someinputfile.txt
```

desired output:

```
someinputfile.txt
```

Comment: The input filename is first available to your `main(String[] args)` as `args[0]`. It is then passed to the parser or scanner. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited my post to be more specific. I've tried referencing args[0] but with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by omitting the `%standalone` tag at the top of the jflex file. This makes jflex not generate the default `main()` method and allows the user to set their own custom `main()` method inside of a `%{ %}` code segment.

Within this `main()`, the user can place the original code for the autogenerated `main()`, but can update to the desired outcome.

Within this context:

```
%%

%class DisplayFilename

%{
  private static String inputfilename = "";
  
  private static class Yytoken {
    /* empty class to allow yylex() to compile */
  }

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    if (argv.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("Usage : java DisplayFilename");
    }
    else {
      int firstFilePos = 0;
      String encodingName = "UTF-8";
      for (int i = firstFilePos; i < argv.length; i++) {
        inputfilename = argv[i]; // LINE OF INTEREST
        WC scanner = null;
        try {
          java.io.FileInputStream stream = new java.io.FileInputStream(argv[i]);
          java.io.Reader reader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream, encodingName);
          scanner = new WC(reader);
          while ( !scanner.zzAtEOF ) scanner.yylex();
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("File not found : \""+argv[i]+"\"");
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
          System.out.println("IO error scanning file \""+argv[i]+"\"");
          System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Unexpected exception:");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  }
%}


%eof{
    /* code to print the input filename goes here */
      System.out.println(inputfilename);
%eof}

%%

\n { /* do nothing */ }
. { /* do nothing */ }
```